# Draing Resources when large file is uploaded

Tags: asp.net

I have a asp.net 4.5 application that's written in c# that allows people to upload files. Our issue is when a large file is uploaded  it slows the entire system down.

We are a virtual server shop. What can be done to alleviate this?

Comment: Define "slow down". What happens exactly? Are you running out of bandwidth, disk throughput, CPU cycles, RAM?

Comment: Disk throughput was totally exhausted, also the system became inoperable for others.

Comment: Get faster disks then.